# MVC5 Bootstrap: Problems with password field (only want masking)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have an application setup where the user must enter access credentials to a 3. party ERP system. This includes a password field, but that field gives me a lot of problems.

The only part of the password field features, that I am aiming for is character masking (that the actual password is not shown). Can I achieve masking by other means?

TIA

Kind regards
S. Dalby

Comment: What problems are you having?  HTML5 uses this without bootstrap to mask input. <input type="password" id="pwd">

Answer (score 2):

This is what you're after.  [Demo](http://css-tricks.com/examples/iPhonePassword/)

http://css-tricks.com/better-password-inputs-iphone-style/

If you're going to go this route, I strongly urge you to leave the last character typed as unmasked so user experience doesn't suffer.  Otherwise, you increase likelihood of invalid logins.

Comment: Hi Ashly, thanks for the attempt, but I could make it work. Part of the problem can be related to that I do not want to use a password field - I want a normal textfield masking text as a password field - there are other behaviours of a password field but masking which is inconvinient for me (sidebar: it did not work for password fields either :) )

Comment: Make sure you're using type="text" when doing the above and NOT using type="password".  That should remove the default browser functionality around the password HTML type and allow you to use javascript to control the functionality.  The demo provided uses type="text" and not type="password".  Sorry it did not work as you had hoped.

Comment: Hi, I tried both, but I have also noted that the developer of the plugin has deprecated it. Likely it does not work with never versions of jquery.